# Safari in iOS - share using

Tags: mobile-safari

There is a "share" button in the bottom of the screen in Safari and I am wondering if it possible to add a custom sharing option for that?

For example if user installed an app (let's say App1) then when you click on that "share" button there will be "App1" in the share options list. App1 should register itself somehow as such that is able to do that. I know that this is possible in Android.